# How do I win over a large protective adopted dog?

Tags: dogs, training, aggression

I'm adopting tonight a female bull mastiff 1.5 years old. I like her, except she was very protective of her owner and suspicious of me, including some barking and growling (we met early morning in an empty street). Her job, I would guess.

How do I win her over?